# Time complexity analysis inconsistency

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have this code :

```
int fun(int n)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        count += 1;
  return count;
}
```

The time complexity of this code can be thought of as `O(n)` because `O(n+n/2+n/4+...) = O(n)`

By that logic, the time complexity of this snippet can also be argued to be `O(n)` :

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
//O(1) statements
```

Since `O(1+2+4+..+n/4+n/2) = O(n)`. But since the loop runs `log(n)` times, it can be `log(n)` too.

Why is the former one not : `log(n)` times the outer loop ***** `log(n)` times the inner loop so, `log(n)log(n)`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should take care of [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are satisfied with one.

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet has the outer loop that executes `O(log n)` times, and each iteration the inner loop executes `O(i)` times. If you sum any number of terms of the form `n / 2^k`, you'll get `O(n)`.

The second piece of code has `O(log n)` iterations of `O(1)` operations, and sum of logarithmic amount of constants is still logarithmic.

Comment: can you elaborate on the statement "If you sum log n terms of form n / 2^k, you'll get O(n)", I get that there will be `log(n)` runs of the outer loop, the inner loop will have `O(i)` on each run.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary, well, the first term is already `O(n)`, so the sum is no less. On the other hard, it's easy to see that `n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...` is less or equal to `n`: indeed, when k=1 the value of the sum `x` is n/2 — precisely a middle point between 0 and n. Each time you add the next term in the sum you move your `x` to the middle point between current `x` and `n`. Obviously, it can't exceed `n`.

Comment: Yes, after the edit, it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of the 2nd one should **not** be calculated as a series `O(1+2+4+..+n/4+n/2) = O(n)`, because it is **not** that series.

---

Notice the first one. It is being calculated as a series because one counts the number of times the inner `for` loop executes and then add all of them (series) to get the final time complexity.

When `i=n` inner `for` loop executes `n` times
When `i=(n/2)` inner `for` loop executes `n/2` times
When `i=(n/4)` inner `for` loop executes `n/4` times
and so on..

---

But in the second one, there is no series to add. It just comes to a formula `(2^x) = n`, which evaluates to `x = logn`.

`(2^x) = n` this formula can be obtained by noticing that `i` starts with `1`, and when it becomes `2` it is multiplied by `2` until it reaches `n`.
So one needs to find out how many times `2` needs to be multiplied by `2` to reach `n`.
Thus the formula `(2^x) = n`, and then solve for `x`.

Comment: The second one can in fact be thought of as a series, `i=1; O(1), i=2;O(1)...` so, effectively `O(log(n)*1) = O(log(n))`. Thanks !

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary, That way too, but I find the way I explained a little simpler and easier to grab.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary, Anyway it is always good to know all the ways of solving, thats the fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you don't have an O(1) statement inside your loop, as you have `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) count += 1`. If in your second example you put the same inner loop of the first example, you are back to the same complexity. The first loop is not `O(n*log(n))`; this is easy to demonstrate because you can find an upper bound in `O(2n)` which is equivalent to `O(n)`.

Comment: I did not understand why the first one is not `O(nlog(n))`. The outer loop runs, `log(n)` times and each time, the inner has `O(n), O(n/2), O(n/4)...`. So, the inner loop has `O(n)` and the outer has `O(log(n))`. Hence, `O(nlog(n))`. Why not ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary The inner loop runs n times only *the first time*. You run the inner loop `log(n)` times, but every time the number of cycles of the inner loop goes down. To have a complexity of `n*log(n)` you would need to have all the inner loops run to be made of `n` cycles, but this is not the case.